# cant perform 2 succesive groupBy in spark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark

I am working with Spark on python.

My problem is: i have a `.csv` file which contains some data (int1, int2, int3, date). I did a `groupByKey` on `int1`. Now I want to perform an other `groupBy` on my date with the rdd create by the first `groupBy`.

Problem is I can't perform it. Any idea?

Regards

EDIT2:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    import csv
    import sys
    import StringIO

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
file = sc.textFile("histories_2week9.csv")

 csvById12Rdd=file.map(lambda (id1,id2,value): ((id1,id2),value)).groupByKey()
 csvById1Rdd=csvById12Rdd.map(lambda ((id1,id2),group):(id1, (id2,group))).groupByKey()



def printit(one):
  id1, twos=one
  print("Id1:{}".format(id1))
    for two in twos:
      id2, values=two
      print("Id1:{} Id2:{}".format(id1,id2))
     for value in values:
        print("Id1:{} Id2:{} Value:{}".format(id1,id2,value))


  csvById12Rdd.first().foreach(printit)
```

the csv is like
31705,48,2,2014-10-28T18:14:09.000Z

EDIT 3:

i can print my iterator data with this code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

import csv
import sys
import StringIO

sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
file = sc.textFile("histories_2week9.csv")

def go_in_rdd2(x):
  print x[0]
  for i in x[1]:
      print i

counts = file.map(lambda line: (line.split(",")[0],line.split(",")[1:]))
counts = counts.groupByKey()
counts.foreach(go_in_rdd2)
```

but i still cant groupBy

Comment: Is there an error message, does your job crash, we need more information to answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by return an RDD of (Key, Iterable[Value]), can you do the otherway round?

1. Group by id1 **and** id2 and get an RDD of ((Id1,Id2), Iterable[Value])
2. Then group by id1 **alone** and get an RDD of (Id1, Iterable[(Id2,Iterable[Value])])

Something like:

```
csv=[(1,1,"One","Un"),(1,2,"Two","Deux"),(2,1,"Three","Trois"),(2,1,"Four","Quatre")]
csvRdd=sc.parallelize(csv)
# Step 1
csvById12Rdd=csvRdd.map(lambda (id1,id2,value1,value2): ((id1,id2),(value1,value2))).groupByKey()
# Step 2
csvById1Rdd=csvById12Rdd.map(lambda ((id1,id2),group):(id1, (id2,group))).groupByKey()
# Print    
def printit(one):
    id1, twos=one
    print("Id1:{}".format(id1))
    for two in twos:
        id2, values=two
        print("Id1:{} Id2:{}".format(id1,id2))
        for value1,value2 in values:
            print("Id1:{} Id2:{} Values:{} {}".format(id1,id2,value1,value2))

csvById1Rdd.foreach(printit)
```

Comment: thank you for you time.  when i try your methd i got an error message when your print func is called i get "ValueError: too many values to unpack" but i think the 2 groupBy works

Comment: I have tested in Spark 1.2.1 with Python 2.7. Do you use Python 3? Do you accept this Answer?

Comment: i use Python 2.7 and spark 1.2.1 too

Comment: I guess you add some values in your tuples. "ValueError: too many values to unpack" that the tuple doesn't have the right size, for example if you wrote something like "one, two=(1,2,3)" (two elements on the left handside and three on three on the right hand side)

Comment: im trying to modify your code to make it works with an csv with 4 filed do you thinks its a good idea ?

Comment: Sorry  but even with just 3 field i still get the  error : for k, v in iterator:
  File "/home/spark/test.py", line 33, in <lambda>
    csvById12Rdd=file.map(lambda (id1,id2,value): ((id1,id2),value)).groupByKey()
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: i modify my CSV to get only 3 fields same problem sorry  for the inconvenient

Comment: still the same error even with your edit and the original csv  :( and i cant start a chat to talk easier with you

Comment: maybe python cant determine what id1,id2,...  correspond without a parallelize

Comment: Use the .map transformation to transform a CSV row (split the string) into a Tuple. Beware that Python's string.split function returns a List and not Tuple.

Comment: what argument provide to my map function ? i use split to get the goods fields

Comment: if you want im on freenode irc chat channel apache-spark